# Speed up or down the audio speed in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I can't find a way to speed up or down the audio speed (pitch) with actionscript (or any other way in flash). Is it possible?

I want to make a small DJ game, with a control to speed up or down from 15% an uploaded mp3. Any idea on how I could implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not awesome at audio stuff, but I think the way you'd do it is to manipulate the ByteArray of the sound:

There's an example here:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/2008/11/first-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/

I'd also suggest looking at Andre Michelle's stuff (http://blog.andre-michelle.com/)

Comment: nice ressources, thanks. I also found:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/dynamic_sound_generation/, 
"The DynamicSoundSample1 sample application adjusts the pitch (frequency) of a sound. The application reads the sound data as a byte array from a loaded MP3 file, and then adjusts the data of the output sound by removing sound samples, which causes the pitch to shift higher"